# How to apply conditions on click event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two functions on one click event. I am trying to apply a condition on it:

- When the button is disabled then `$event.stopPropagation()` should be called.
- When the button is enabled then `editVersionDetails()` should be called.

Below is my code:

```
<button mat-icon-button class="editApp" [disabled]="app.d"
  (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); editVersionDetails()">
    <mat-icon  aria-label="Example edit icon">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: I would handle the logic inside the component. Pass a "onClick()" function to you (click) binding. I guess you'd also need to keep track of your 'disabled' value in the component and use it to disable your button.

Comment: oh but wait a second, how do you want to trigger a (click) if your button is disabled?

Comment: My edit icon is in checkbox area so I want to apply $event.stopPropagation() when edit icon is disable. Now when edit is disable and if I click on in then it uncheck checkbox.
My button is in for loop. When app.d is true then only it is disabled

Comment: Sorry don't understand why do you need to fire `event.stopPropagation()`  for a 'disabled' button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple you can do it like this..**

```
<button mat-icon-button class="editApp" [disabled]="app.d"
  (click)="app.d ? $event.stopPropagation() : editVersionDetails()">
    <mat-icon  aria-label="Example edit icon">edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```